# Blackberry UEM REST API 401 Unauthorised error

Tags: blackberry, mdm

Unable to perform any authorized API calls using the Blackberry UEM REST API service. I'm running a trial cloud instance of Blackbery UEM and calls to "ping" and "authorization" works. However, after obtaining the authorization code, using it on any REST calls fails with the error 401 Unauthorized.

The credential used is of an administrator with the "Security Administrator" role which has full permission. I have also tried the above in postman and also the sample PowerShell command, but the results are the same.

Does anyone know what's going on wrong here? Am I missing any configuration? I am going a bit crazy... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you get a 401 error, its almost always an issue with the account/authorization your using.
Since your connecting to the cloud instance of UEM, it ONLY support OAuth authentication.  For this to work, you will need an token, not an authorization code.  Here is a devblog.blackberry.com entry on the steps: https://devblog.blackberry.com/en/2020/07/new-authentication-option-for-rest-apis-oauth.
Give that a try instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It saved my day. Wasn't obvious that the cloud version supports only the oauth.